# Understanding stack when passing object to param

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new with C++, trying to understand some stack issues.

In the code bellow, `list` is created in the stack, right? So each string item is stored in a stack position (its address). Now, when I pass `list` in the reference param of `QStringListModel(const QStringList &strings, ...)` the list is not copied, but just a reference(addr) is passed in, right? So it remains in the same stack scope of the method? If list really resides in the stack how it is not destroyed when its scope finish? If it remains, as soon I add new items to list, inside the model, will the stack grow/shrink?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    // ...

    QStringList list;
    list << "aaa" << "bbb" << "ccc";
    QStringListModel *model = new QStringListModel(list, this);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: although StringList is on the stack, it is just a management structure for strings stored elsewhere (e.g. pointer to a head of a linked list)

Comment: @Jimmy so it works just because its items resides in tho heap? So another simpler structure wouldn't work. But how `model` takes control of the list if the management structure is destroyed?

Comment: you need to ensure that your string list outlives your QStringListModel - when list goes out of scope it will clean up its strings (not necessarily on the heap). What your model does when this happens is probably not what you want ;-)

Comment: I think QStringList is a typedef for QVector<QString>

Comment: @Jimmy No. `QStringList` is a subclass of `QList<QString>`. So it is basically a `QList<QString>` with some extra functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `list` is valid until the `MainWindow` constructor returns. It is also correct that `QStringListModel` does not receive a copy of the list.

`QStringListModel` can only inspect the list inside the constructor call, if it wants to keep some information, it has to make its own copy.

This is not guaranteed nor enforced by the compiler, but it is common practice. A function that stores a reference, or completely takes ownership of an object, should always be documented to do that, exactly because of the reason you have just found.

Comment: Even though it's a reference param, `QStringListModel` (or compiler) can create another structure (`QStringList`) to manage the list items?

Comment: Theoretically, it could, but the problem would be that the original list deletes all objects it has allocated when it goes out of scope, so the second control structure would have invalid pointers after that. That's why `QStringListModel` has to make a complete copy.

Comment: So actually this code works just because how `QStringList` was implemented, otherwise it couldn't work?

Comment: It depends entirely on the implementation of `QStringListModel`. If it stores the reference to the list, that fact is surely documented.

Comment: ..or maybe `QStringList` has some mechanism that `QStringListModel` can use to make its content live longer than the original object, I don't know...

Comment: @Fabricio `QStringListModel` makes a copy of the `QStringList` passed. This is a shallow copy, it won't be deep copied until the original `QStringList` is modified (e.g. destroyed). [Here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/2381e38337c6d3ad536be5f25ac071e1c3a8002b:src/gui/itemviews/qstringlistmodel.cpp#L103) is the source code of the `QStringListModel` constructor. Check [`QStringList::QStringList ( const QStringList & other )`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstringlist.html#QStringList-3) from the docs.

Comment: You can read about implicit sharing [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/implicit-sharing.html#implicitly-shared).